# Did Chaitanya Mahaprabhu author a commentary on the Brahma Sutras in Prakashananda Math?

Tags: brahma-sutras, vivekananda, gaudiya-vaishnavism, chaitanya

While going through [this letter](https://en.m.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda/Volume_6/Epistles_-_Second_Series/IX_Sir) by Swami Vivekananda dated 17th August 1889, I stumbled across a line where Swamiji talks about an apparent rumour of Sri Chaitanya Mahaprabhu authoring a commentary on the Brahma Sutras:

> 3. Chaitanya-deva is said to have told Sârvabhauma at Puri, "I understand the Sutras (aphorisms) of Vyasa, they are dualistic; but the commentator makes them, monistic, which I don't understand." Is this true? Tradition says, Chaitanya-deva had a dispute with Prakashananda Sarasvati on the point, and Chaitanya-deva won. **One commentary by Chaitanya-deva was rumoured to have been existing in Prakashananda's Math**.

Again, in one of his [Madras addresses](https://en.m.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda/Volume_4/Writings:_Prose/Reply_to_the_Madras_address), Swami Vivekananda mentions a commentary on the Brahma Sutras of having being written by Sri Chaitanya:

> **The commentary that Shri Chaitanya wrote on the Vyâsa-Sutras has either been lost or not found yet.** His disciples joined themselves to the Madhvas of the South, and gradually the mantles of such giants as Rupa and Sanâtana and Jiva Goswâmi fell on the shoulders of Bâbâjis, and the great movement of Shri Chaitanya was decaying fast, till of late years there is a sign of revival. Hope that it will regain its lost splendour.

Now as far as I know, the only existing work of Sri Chaitanya Mahaprabhu is the "[Siksastakam](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.atmaramadasa.org/pdf/SRI%2520SIKSASTAKAM.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwib_ZjtlLngAhXGbX0KHQRGASYQFjACegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw2qIw6hKaXd3wXWHnA8luCJ&cshid=1550076494239)". Also, the only Gaudiya Vaishnava commentary on the Brahma Sutras I know of, is Baladeva Vidyabhusana's "[Govinda Bhashya](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.vrindavana.net/academy/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Vedanta-sutra-Govinda-Bhasya-Baladeva-Vidyabhusana-I.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwj9p5-flbngAhXKQ30KHeuDDkkQFjACegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw0kh7EK0lSs2X_-ww87RU-V)".

So my question is:

Is there any evidence of Sri Chaitanya authoring such a commentary? Do any reliable Gaudiya sources mention Mahaprabhu ever writing such a commentary?

Comment: In another letter, Swami Vivekananda wrote - "The commentary that Shri Chaitanya wrote on the Vyâsa-Sutras has either been lost or not found yet" So it seems like at least Swami Vivekananda was very clear that Chaitanyadeva indeed wrote a commentary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no mention of Mahaprabhu's writing of any commentary after returning from Gaya where He was initiated by Sripad Ishwara Puri. His biographies say that He remained always in a very exalted state intoxicated by Love of God since then. The incidents of the authentic biographies make it clear that it was NOT possible for Him either physically or mentally (despite being Almighty He remainned in a bhakta state most of the time) to write any such commentary. Except the Shikshastakam, which are if two or four lines each, no composition of Him is mentioned in His biographies.

Swamiji in all probabilities commented this based on some hearsay.